# How to display cluster graph with R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, k-means

I am using k-means clustering using R and I divide the data set with two clusters

```
clus.data <- df[,1:14]
head(clus.data)
heart.cluster <- kmeans(clus.data,2)
```

how to plot the graph with cluster to view them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I should point out is that you should scale your data set before k-means as a form of standardisation of the data (if you haven't scaled it already that is!):-

```
clus.data <- df[,1:14]
head(clus.data)
scaledData<-scale(clus.data)
heart.cluster <- kmeans(scaledData,2)
```

You could use the `factoextra` package.

```
library(factoextra) # clustering algorithms & visualization
```

And to visualise:

```
fviz_cluster(heart.cluster, data = scaledData)
```